# Detect if datastream fulfills condition (threshold) X times in a specific time Y in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, threshold, data-stream

In a datastream, I try to detect of a certain threshold (condition) is met. Additionally, the threshold should not apply to spontaneous noise (spikes), also spontaneous low values in a fulfilled condition should also not stop me from detecting the area of values above `X`.

The data comes in sample by sample in a datastream and I am still searching for a pythonic/fast solution. The following image explains my problem visually:
[image]
The aim is to save the starting index and end index of a detected section that fulfills the condition of exceeding a certain threshold `X` times.

I am struggling with the data coming in one at a time, on a whole data set it wouldn't be a problem. I thought of something like this:

```
threshold = 5
start_index_list = []

while i < len(data):  # just to show that it's one datapoint at a time
    if data(i) > threshold:
         threshold_counter +=1 
         if threshold_counter > threshold_counter_level:  # consecutive true conditions
             start_index = i - threshold_counter_level
             start_index_list.append(start_index)
    else:
         threshold_counter = 0  # if condition breaks, counter is reset

    i += 1  # increment iteration variable
```

Problem here is that if counter start to increment a single false event stops it. But I want detect if for example 90% of the values in a window of let's say 50 consecutive values are true, it's not important whether after the first 3 values there is a value below the threshold, I still need the `starting_index` and the `end_index` of the whole area.

Sorry for the rather complicated description, it's just so frustrating to not find a solution in case of a datastream. If there are still questions or something is unclear, I will edit my answer.